# Undefined parameter name error in Hspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, homework, pspice, hspice

I am trying to run this Hspice code in Spectre.

[image]

I am getting this error

[image]

Can anyone help me what is the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure HSPICE supports doing a `.DC` command on a resistor?  Typically in SPICE, you can only do that to independent voltage and/or current sources.  i.e. only things that start with `V` or `I`, not `R`.

Comment: @SteKulov Yes, In the manual, it was written for a resistor like that so I used it.

Comment: @Rohit Then my answer doesn't apply to your case, I deleted it. I can't help you since I don't know HSPICE and, AFAIK, it's known to handle SPICE-related things quite unusually. Best ask in their forums.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I wouldn't have gone that far.  It's not clear in the original post, but he's using Spectre and not HSPICE.  Spectre's SPICE parser doesn't look like it supports HSPICE's extended `.DC` command.  That's likely where the issue is.

Comment: @Rohit Try changing `R2` to `V1` and see if it works. If it does, then it obeys the usual SPICE rules, which means you can only use voltage or current sources for `.DC`.

Comment: @SteKulov Well, whatever the case, my answer didn't solve OP's problems, since in the comments OP wrote something about an `unknown parameter [x]`. So it's another quirk in interpretation of commands, or maybe only the curly braces, who knows? I don't, so I make room for someone else who does.

Answer (score 0):

Change print V(2) to print or plot V(2,0). Voltage differential between 2 and 0.

Comment: same error I am getting